# how to Use python to find a line number in a document and insert data underneath it

Tags: python, search, python-3.x, replace

Hi I already have the search function sorted out:

```
def searchconfig():
    config1 = open("config.php", "r")
    b='//cats'
    for num, line in enumerate(config1,0):
        if b in line:
            connum = num + 1
            return connum
   config1.close()
```

This will return the line number of //cats, I then need to take the data underneath it put it in a tempoary document, append new data under the //cats and then append the data in the tempoary document to the original? how would i do this? i know that i would have to use 'a' instead of 'r' when opening the document but i do not know how to utilise the line number.

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: What is the new data that you want to add?

Comment: @HerrActress i just want to add a string such as "<host = xyz>" where host is a user in put

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the easiest way would be to read the whole file into a list of strings, work on that list and write it back afterwards.

```
# Read all lines of the file into a list of strings
with open("config.php", "r") as file:
  lines = list(file)
  file.close()

# This gets the line number for the first line containing '//cats'
# Note that it will throw an StopIteration exception, if no such line exists...
linenum = (num for (num, line) in enumerate(lines) if '//cats' in line).next()

# insert a line after the line containing '//cats'
lines.insert(linenum+1, 'This is a new line...')

# You could also replace the line following '//cats' like
lines[linenum+1] = 'New line content...'

# Write back the file  (in fact this creates a new file with new content)
# Note that you need to append the line delimiter '\n' to every line explicitely
with open("config.php", "w") as file:
  file.writelines(line + '\n' for line in lines)
  file.close()
```

Using `"a"` as mode for `open` would only let you append ath the end of the file.

You could use `"r+"` for a combined read/write mode, but then you could only *overwrite* some parts of the file, there is no simple way to *insert* new lines in the middle of the file using this mode.

Comment: i get a syntax error during this part with (file = open("config.php", "r")):' it says that global variable file is not defined? i dont know what is wrong as it is not global at all?

Comment: @Downdog555 Sorry, I was thinking C# while writing the `with` statement (it corresponds roughly to C#'s `using`...) I fixed the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this. I am creating a new file in this example as it is usually safer.

```
with open('my_file.php') as my_php_file:
  add_new_content = ['%sNEWCONTENT' %line if '//cat' in line
                     else line.strip('\n')
                     for line in my_php_file.readlines()]
with open('my_new_file.php', 'w+') as my_new_php_file:
  for line in add_new_content:
    print>>my_new_php_file, line
```